# LATEX Hyperref not working (getting thrown a bun of (?,?) in citations)

Tags: latex, overleaf, hyperref

I am currently finishing my thesis and wanted to include hyperref to make my layout a bit more reader-friendly. However, I am getting a bunch over error when using the package. Any help is much appreciated! My main is as follows

`\documentclass[12pt]{article}`
`\usepackage[a4paper, top=30mm, bottom=30mm, left=27.5mm, right=27.5mm]{geometry}`
`\linespread{1.25}`
`\usepackage[splitrule]{footmisc}`
`\interfootnotelinepenalty=10000 %% Completely prevent breaking of footnotes`
`\usepackage{graphicx}`
`\usepackage{float}`
`\usepackage{multirow}`
`\usepackage{booktabs}`
`\usepackage{derivative}`
`\usepackage{amsmath}`
`\usepackage{array}`
`\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmin}{arg\,min}`
`\usepackage{breqn}`
`\usepackage{apacite}`
`\usepackage{rotating}`
`\usepackage{longtable}`
`\usepackage{subfig}`
`\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}`
`\usepackage{euscript}`
`\usepackage{bm}`
`\usepackage{amssymb}`
`\usepackage{longtable}`
`\usepackage{relsize}`
`\usepackage{lscape}`
`\usepackage{threeparttable}`
`\usepackage{caption}`
`\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}`
`\usepackage{fancyhdr}`
`\usepackage[unicode, colorlinks, linkcolor=Black]{hyperref}`
`\definecolor{linkcolor}{HTML}{000000}`
`\definecolor{urlcolor}{HTML}{000000}`
`\hypersetup{pdfstartview=FitH, linkcolor=linkcolor, urlcolor=urlcolor, colorlinks=True}`
`\pagenumbering{roman}`
`\begin{document}`

I tried various variations of the hyperref command (and reaching out to chatGPT), and nothing helped.

Comment: Not really on-topic here, consider asking at [TeX-LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

There are three errors in your code:

- you must not load the same package multiple times with different options. Error messages in the log file will inform you about this problem with both the footmisc package as well as graphicx
- if you want to use `\definecolor` you need to load a package which defines this macro first, e.g. xcolor

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article} \usepackage[a4paper, top=30mm, bottom=30mm, left=27.5mm, right=27.5mm]{geometry} \linespread{1.25} \usepackage[splitrule]{footmisc} \interfootnotelinepenalty=10000 %% Completely prevent breaking of footnotes 
\usepackage{graphicx} \usepackage{float} \usepackage{multirow} \usepackage{booktabs} \usepackage{derivative} \usepackage{amsmath} \usepackage{array} \DeclareMathOperator*{\argmin}{arg\,min} \usepackage{breqn} \usepackage{apacite} \usepackage{rotating} \usepackage{longtable} \usepackage{subfig} 
%\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}
 \usepackage{euscript} \usepackage{bm} \usepackage{amssymb} \usepackage{longtable} \usepackage{relsize} \usepackage{lscape} \usepackage{threeparttable} \usepackage{caption} 
% \usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx} 
 \usepackage{fancyhdr} 
 \usepackage{xcolor}
 \usepackage[unicode, colorlinks, linkcolor=Black]{hyperref} \definecolor{linkcolor}{HTML}{000000} \definecolor{urlcolor}{HTML}{000000} \hypersetup{pdfstartview=FitH, linkcolor=linkcolor, urlcolor=urlcolor, colorlinks=True} \pagenumbering{roman} 
\begin{document}

test

\end{document}
```